# When should you run migrations on a pull request?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, git, migrate

Sorry for such a noob question - new to git and ruby on rails.

I am on a school coding team writing an app in rails. One of the pull requests has a new database on it, but the migrations have not been run (rake db:migrate).

Should we run the migration on the branch first and then merge to master or merge to master and then do rake db:migrate on the master branch?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's better practice to:

1. run `rake db:migrate`
2. commit to repo

because `db:migrate` modifies your `db/schema.rb` file, which displays "current" state of the database. It's super important to have latest version of this file in your repo.

Also note the comment in `db/schema.rb`:

```
# It's strongly recommended to check this file into your version control system.
```

Hence the recommended order above.

Answer (score 1):

If you're checking someone's work (i.e. it's not your pull request, but they say it's ready and it's your job to merge it), then you should checkout the branch and test if the migrations are ok, because if you merge it to master (and push it, so everybody can get the update) and migrations are not ok, then everyone will be frustrated because of the broken master branch.

That's why I recommend to checkout the branch, run migrations, and then merge PR to the master and push it upstream.

---

If it's your pull request and you're sure that everything is fine (or you work alone on the project), then there's no specific order: just make sure you don't forget all the steps (merge and migrate).

When I do it myself I usually already have migrations applied (because I needed them for the work in my branch), so it's usually just the case of going to master and merge the branch.

Answer (score 0):

You should always run your migrations before merging to master because you'll want to know if that code worked properly and everything is OK.  Remember running a migration will change your db/schema.rb file and if something is incorrect the server won't start properly or something will fail.

As for whether or not to run the migration before you commit to the branch, that depends on what you're doing.  If you're team coding and need to review work first, go ahead and commit, so others can check out the branch and review.

Answer (score 0):

Why would someone open a pull request on a branch that has new migrations that haven't been run yet? How does the author of the pull request know that the migrations were written correctly?

If I were reviewing the pull request, I'd expect migrations to be run before merging the branch to master. Also, be sure that your schema.rb is getting checked in with the migrations.

Comment: yeah, this was a point of contention on our team. the person who did this argued that it's better to run rake db:migrate on the master branch to ensure that there would be no db bugs. That didn't make sense to me because of the reasons you stated.